# django form wizard doesn't keep the request.FILES when form is invalid?

Tags: django, forms

Lets say I have a form that has two fields - name and image, both required, and is part of a FormWizard.
When I leave the "name" field blank but fill out the "image" field (which is an ImageField and so renders to a  tag) the form is not valid and so the wizard doesn't advance to the next step.
but - the imagefield now "loses" its value - when I fill the name (which is the only error i see) and submitting the form again, the form is invalid because it says the image is missing.

A similar thing happens if i fill both fields and then submit - the form validates, the wizard advances to the next form, and if I get back one step at the wizard the name is filled correctly as i left it but the ImageField loses its value again and I need to re-fill it.

Is this normal behavior? is there something that can be done so this doesn't happen and the value is kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd post this as a comment but I don't have the reputation points.

My issue is similar; however, I'm dealing with inline formsets which bring along their own set of problems.

This is a possible solution that does not work for me - [FormWizard and FileFields (Django 1.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597021/formwizard-and-filefields-django-1-4)

Comment: Thanks! the idea itself works so I don't "lose" the file during the wizard's back and forth movement and that is my original question. But if I want to display the uploaded image to the user, I need a URL, and so an additional workaround is needed: I disabled the InMemoryUploadedFile by setting the FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE to be 0 so it is always saved to disk and I changed the FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR to a known directory through MEDIA_ROOT and passed this path/URL to the template through a context variable so I can display it.

Comment: Yeah - it does. Got my wizard working a while ago but in a slightly different manner. The wizard by default uploads the files in a temporary location set by the `file_storage` attribute ([WizardView.file_storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.file_storage)) and I'm using that in a custom `ImageField` widget to display the image to the user.