# Keeping files between steps using FormWizard

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard, django-1.6

Due to registration form for my application being a bit too long for one page I decided to use a `SessionWizard`.

I managed to make it work for me, but there's still one thing that irks me - my form requires user to upload several files, and each time there's something wrong with that step (i.e. `ValidationError`) or user decides to go back a step, and then come back, the files are lost and need to be uploaded again.

I found similar (identical, in fact) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597021/formwizard-and-filefields-django-1-4), but the solution didn't work for me - probably because of the changes to FormWizards from Django 1.4.

Do you have any suggestions on writing custom `get_form` method, or any other approach to the problem?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here's the code for said wizard:

```
class CompanyRegistrationWizard(SessionWizardView):
file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
template_name = 'register/wizard_form.html'

def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
    joined_data = {}
    for ob in form_data:
        joined_data.update(ob)
    save_from_the_form_data(self.request, joined_data)
    mailer_engage(joined_data)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
```

Comment: Have you added `file_storage` in your wizard? Show us your code.

Comment: @Rohan I added the wizard's code. Should I paste anything else?